# How can I have a variable's value be a method, and have a method use that variable in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to have a variable have the value of a method, so when I run the variable I run a method. This only works if I create the variable after the method. However, I also want to use that variable in the same method it runs. That only works if I create the variable before the method.

```
def test():
    testing()

def testing():
    print "hello"
    var

var = test()
var
```

So when I run this program, it tells me "global name 'var' is not defined." And if I create the variable before the method like so,

```
var = test()

def test():
    testing()

def testing():
    print "hello"
    var

var
```

it tells me "name 'test' is not defined"

I do mean function when I say method. And when I say run the method, I am referring to the line that says 'var'

What I am asking is how can I have a variable's value be the name of a method, and have that variable be used in another method.

Comment: When you say "method" do you mean "function?"

Comment: You have a chicken-and-egg problem. You want to use `var` in `testing()`, but you can't assign to `var` until after `test()` calls `testing()`.

Comment: And what do you mean "when I run the variable, I run the method (function?)" that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why is `var ` just floating there doing nothing? Is this something you did in the REPL?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what running a variable means? Do you mean just getting its value? You could look at the `@property` decorator, which calls a function each time a variable is accessed (can also do similar when variable is assigned to). This is the closest I can think to the first part of your requirements. The second part however makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the line:

```
var = test()
```

you're *not* actually assigning the function `test` to the variable `var`. You're assigning the expression `test()`. The parentheses after `test` mean you're **calling** the function `test`, and the expression is the value *resulting* from that call. *That's* what you're assigning to `var`.

Because this call occurs in the assignment statement that creates `var`, it has to be carried out before `var` actually exists. So when `test` calls `testing`, `testing` tries to access `var`, which doesn't exist yet. That's your error.

What you need to do instead is to just assign the function `test` directly to `var`, without calling it:

```
var = test
```

This leaves `var` bound to the function. Note that to use this, you have to use parentheses to actually call it, so you need `var()` on the next line, not just `var`.

Note that `test` itself is *just an ordinary variable that happens to be bound to a function*. The `def` statement basically just creates a function object, sets that function object's `__name__` value to `"test"`, and binds the variable `test`, all at the same time.

If in your real use case, you need to pass some arguments to `test` and you don't want to have to know about those when you call `var`, then what you instead want to do is create a zero-argument wrapper function that calls `test` when it is called, like this:

```
def var():
    return test(some, arguments, here)
```

You can do that as a local definition in a function just fine, it doesn't have to be created separately at module scope. Alternatively, you could create a nameless lambda function, which you can do as an expression rather than needing a separate definition:

```
var = lambda: test(some, arguments, here)
```

But you'll still always need to use parentheses to call `var`, like `var()`; you'll never be able to call it by just writing `var`.